# Modal won't center align

Tags: html, modal-dialog, dreamweaver

My modal does not seem to fit in the center of the page , I am running on bootstrap 4 atm, Can someone please try me what I need to do ?

```
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                
                            <div class="Modal-header">
                    
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-plain-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    
                                    </div>
                    
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                
                                        <img src="<?=$base_url?>_images/animation.gif" alt="Animated Gif">
                
                                    </div>
                        
                                </div>
                    
                            </div>
                
                        </div>
            
                    </div>
    
                </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your order of classes are wrong, and you used the class `modal-dialog` twice as well.

Replace your modal code with this:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="<?=$base_url?>_images/animation.gif" alt="Animated Gif">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Copied and edited from [Bootstrap 4.6 Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/)

Comment: Thanks man it worked, Could you maybe help me with one more thing ?

Comment: Glad to know. Please post a new question for any other questions.

Comment: It says I can only ask every 90 mins

Comment: Aha okay. Maybe now then, need to follow the rules. :)